# Get default backup path of sql server programmatically

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup

I am taking backups of certain sql server databases programmatically using c#. I figured that Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo and some other libraries are made for this purpose. Now I can backup a database. Very nice. Here is the code :

```
var server = new Server(@"" + InstanceName);
var backuper = new Backup();
try
{
    backuper.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
    backuper.Database = DbName;
    backuper.Devices.AddDevice(DbName + ".bak", DeviceType.File);
    backuper.BackupSetName = DbName + " - Yedek";
    backuper.BackupSetDescription = "Açık Bulut Depo - " + DbName + " - Yedek";
    backuper.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(20);
    server.ConnectionContext.Connect();
    backuper.SqlBackup(server); 
}
catch(Exception ex){//..}
```

My question here is how can I get the path of the device that the database backed up into?
I know I can specify my own path as :

```
backuper.Devices.AddDevice("C:\SOMEPATH\" + DbName + ".bak", DeviceType.File);
```

Then I can actually know where it is, but what I want to do is back it up to its default location and get its path. Please help me out with this.

Comment: Maybe once the backup is complete, you can find the most recent backup set associated with the database and work it out from there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From this blog post, you could use the function below:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1966/function-to-return-default-sql-server-backup-folder/

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_SQLServerBackupDir() 
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000) 
 AS 
BEGIN 

 DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(4000) 

EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regread 
        N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
        N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer',N'BackupDirectory', 
        @path OUTPUT,  
        'no_output' 
RETURN @path 
END;
```

Comment: how can I call this from c#?

Comment: It would need to be a separate db call than the SMO code above; you would call it the same way you would call any sql select statement: "SELECT   dbo.fn_SQLServerBackupDir() as backuppath" and then read the results .

Comment: Thank you it worked like a charm :) my only concern now is that this software is supposed to be used on several databases by some end users who wants to create a backups of their databases, what if the user that they connect to database with does not have necessary privilages to create functions?

Comment: You don't necessarily need the function, they do need permission however to execute master.dbo.xp_instance_regread which you could try to call another way. Not sure there is a workaround if they can't be granted that permission.

Answer (score 9):

Correct Answer to this duplicate can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8791588/331889

```
Server.BackupDirectory;
```

Given you are already using SMO Objects it should be the simplest answer.

Answer (score 0):

I normally execute the below stored procedure immediately after `backuper.SqlBackup(server);`
to return the most recent backup destination path. I use this approach because using SMO, i give the application user the flexibility of backing up to any location / drive or even to a USB disk. So a user may decide not to backup to the default backup location and i want to return that location after the backup process is successfully completed.

```
  USE [YouDatabaseNameHere]
    GO

    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    -- =============================================
    -- Author:      SQL.NET Warrior
    -- =============================================
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBackupHistory]
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @SQLVer SQL_VARIANT
            ,@DBName VARCHAR(128)
            ,@NumDays   SMALLINT
            ,@SQL       VARCHAR(1024)
            ,@WhereClause   VARCHAR(256)

    SET @DBName = Null
    ;
    SET @NumDays = 14
    ;
    SET @SQLVer = CONVERT(INTEGER, PARSENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')),4));

    SET @WhereClause = 'WHERE a.type IN (''D'',''I'')
            And a.backup_start_date > GETDATE()- ' + CAST(@NumDays AS VARCHAR)+''
    IF @DBName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + '
            AND a.database_name = '''+ @DBName +''''
    END

    SET @SQL = '
    SELECT TOP 1 a.database_name,a.backup_start_date
            ,b.physical_device_name AS BackupPath
            ,a.position
            ,a.type
            ,a.backup_size/1024/1024 AS BackupSizeMB
            ,' + CASE 
                WHEN @SQLVer < 10 
                    THEN '0'
                    ELSE 'a.compressed_backup_size/1024/1024'
                END + ' AS CompressedBackMB
        FROM msdb.dbo.backupset a
            INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily b
                ON a.media_set_id = b.media_set_id
        ' + @WhereClause + '
        ORDER BY a.backup_start_date DESC;';
         --PRINT @SQL
     EXECUTE (@SQL);
    END;



    GO
```